# Javascript/Jquery: .css pixel-values

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I just realised there is a difference between

```
<foo>.css('marginTop')
```

(which I thought is the standard jquery-notation) and

```
<foo>.css('margin-top')
```

(which I thought was non-standard).

If  has margin-top: 3em; (for example), the first notation gives me 3em, the second notation gives me 48px (which is 3em in Pixels).
I like this behaviour but I could not find anything about it in the API (or am I blind?)

Why is this the case and where can I find information about it?

P.S.: Just to be precise: of course other attributes but margin-top work aswell...

Thank you!

Comment: Which browsers are exhibiting this behavior?

Comment: by now I've tested it with Firefox only. But since JSizes (http://www.bramstein.com/projects/jsizes/) seems to take advantage of the same functions as I did, I'm quite optimistic at least the "dash-notation" works in other browsers as well.
By the way thanks a lot for your reply!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The doc says “jQuery can equally interpret the CSS and DOM formatting of multiple-word properties”, but in reality it is doing that through rough and ready hacks which don't always behave predictably.

In particular, if you supply a DOM-style `camelCaseName`, it will first try to access the inline style declaration as `style.camelCaseName`. Then if that fails (typically because the style was not set inline), it falls back to trying `getComputedStyle` with the `camelCaseName` converted to `hyphen-separated-name`(*). The computed style is not the same thing as the declared style: the browser can resolve various relative declarations in a computed style, such as converting lengths to pixel units.

However, the reverse does not hold! If you supply a CSS-style `hyphen-separated-name`, it jumps straight to the computed style(*) code without trying to convert to `camelCaseName` and look at the inline style.

I don't think I'd want to rely on this behaviour... it smells a little bit buggy to me. If you can keep the inline style declaration off the element you want to measure, you should be able to ensure you always get the computed style back regardless of which name type you use. But then again, jQuery doesn't give you that as a documented promise. Such is the nature of trying to hide a complicated model behind a seemingly-simple “Do What I Mean” interface.

(*): except in IE where there is no `getComputedStyle` function, so it falls back to a weird and fragile mix of `currentStyle`, `runtimeStyle` and document alteration to try to get a computed style out.

Comment: I can confirm this after looking at the code and this is a much better explanation.  Unfortunately, doing so resulting in VS 2010 Beta crashing my PC and forcing me to restart rather ironically while I was mid-way through downloading the RC.  Oh well, it is a beta!

Comment: Oh and I should add that IE will not exhibit this behavior because as @bobince pointed out, it doesn't use `getComputedStyle`, and `currentStyle` returns the value in `em` if it's specified in `em`, unlike `getComputedStyle` which returns `px`.

Comment: thank you very much for this explanation and thank you, Andy, espacially for even crashing your PC for answering me ;-)

Where can I read about getComputedStyle then?

Comment: another thing:
in this case, Jsizes (http://www.bramstein.com/projects/jsizes/) doesn't work aswell in IE with em- or %-values, right?

Comment: The standard defining it is http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSSview-getComputedStyle, but https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM:window.getComputedStyle is a bit more readable. Haven't played with Jsizes any.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is related to CSS and JavaScript notation of the same thing. It would not be in the jQuery API but in a CSS reference.

CSS uses the margin-top while JavaScript uses the marginTop for the same thing. The default value in CSS (margin-top) is 0px. Therefore you get the 48px instead of the 3em.

See http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_reference.asp for more info.

Comment: sounds good, thank you!
In this case, can I rely on always getting a px-value when I use the "dash-notation"?

Comment: The DOM property and the CSS property are linked.  If I set one, access to the other should be the same.  I don't understand how your answer explains the behavior questioned by @Marcel.

Comment: It is the diff between em and px. CSS is using px by default while JavaScript seems to be using em by default.